# How can I Create a generic procedure for inserting data from a table?

Tags: sql, plsql

I have a table:

```
create table D_DEFAULT
(
  table_name   VARCHAR2(200),
  column_name  VARCHAR2(200),
  column_value VARCHAR2(200)
);
```

| TABLE_NAME | COLUMN_NAME | COLUMN_VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| GCG_RTM | ID | -1 |
| GCG_RTM | FILIAL_CODE | US |
| GCG_RTM | SK_ID | -1 |
| GCG_RTM | SUBS_ID | -1 |

In my project i have to take data from columns COLUMN_NAME and COLUMN_VALUE
and insert it into another table.

Something like this:

```
select LISTAGG(COLUMN_NAME, ','), LISTAGG(COLUMN_VALUE,  ',')
  into v_columns, v_values
  from D_DEFAULT
  where TABLE_NAME = p_table || '_RTM';
```

```
v_sql := 'insert into table ' || p_table || ' values (' || v_values|| ') ';
```

Comment: Please tag your database. Also, the question is not clear - for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is dynamic SQL you need (as you more or less figured out yourself).

Sample data and table:

```
SQL> select * From d_default;

TABLE_NAME      COLUMN_NAME     COLUMN_VALUE
--------------- --------------- ---------------
GCG_RTM         ID              -1
GCG_RTM         FILIAL_CODE     US

SQL> desc gcg_rtm
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                                 NUMBER
 FILIAL_CODE                                        VARCHAR2(5)
```

Code:

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_tab  varchar2(30);
  3    l_cols varchar2(200);
  4    l_vals varchar2(200);
  5    l_str  varchar2(2000);
  6  begin
  7    select table_name,
  8           listagg(column_name, ',') within group (order by rowid),
  9           chr(39) || listagg(column_value, chr(39) ||','|| chr(39)) within group (order by rowid) ||chr(39)
 10    into l_tab, l_cols, l_vals
 11    from d_default
 12    where table_name = 'GCG_RTM'
 13    group by table_name;
 14
 15    l_str := 'insert into ' || l_tab || ' (' ||
 16              l_cols ||') values (' || l_vals || ')';
 17
 18    execute immediate l_str;
 19  end;
 20  /

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from gcg_rtm;

        ID FILIA
---------- -----
        -1 US

SQL>
```

---

Problems you can expect: different datatypes. It is easy to insert strings or numbers (and rely on Oracle's implicit datatype conversion), but - what about e.g. dates? How to apply `TO_DATE` function? Which format model will you use? Maybe your `D_DEFAULT` table lacks in some more info - at least `datatype` and `format_model`.

Comment: Yes, it's a good question. I can add new column in my table d_default, with datatype and format_model. But how can I set it before inserting data to target tables?

Comment: Exactly - you **should** set the whole D_DEFAULT table up **before** running this procedure. Otherwise, in my opinion, it doesn't make sense. D_DEFAULT should be ready for processing; it shouldn't be subject of any changes at the moment you run this procedure.